# unable to use Sigilless variables with WHERE clause in CLASS?

Tags: where-clause, predicate, raku

Module **A** has a member variable name `c`, with a WHERE clause:

```
unit class A;

my \MAXVALUE = 1000_000;

has $.c where 0 < * < MAXVALUE;

method gist() {
    "$!c";
}
```

set **RAKULIB** environment variable:

```
set RAKULIB="d:\scripts\Raku\A\lib"      # Windows
export RAKULIB="/opt/scripts/Raku/A/lib" # Linux
```

use Module A like this:

```
use A;

my $a = A.new(c => 1);
say $a;
```

but got type check error:

```
Type check failed in binding to parameter '<anon>'; expected Any but got Mu (Mu)
  in whatevercode  at D:\scripts\Raku\Raku\A\lib\.precomp\C6EB86CB837D3BCAAA3D85B66CE337C820700C08\6D\6DCD4CE23D88E2EE9568BA546C007C63D9131C1B line 1
  in block <unit> at basic.rakutest line 3
```

Is this a bug?

raku version:

```
raku -v
This is Rakudo version 2020.05.1 built on MoarVM version 2020.05
implementing Raku 6.d.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Golfed to:** `BEGIN say 1 < Mu` displays essentially the same error message.

In your code, `MAXVALUE` is initialized with the value `Mu` at compile time. You must alter your code so evaluation of `... < MAXVALUE` comes *after* `MAXVALUE` has been initialized to have a value other than `Mu`.

In the rest of this answer:

- **What are the simplest compile time solutions?**
- **What if you want to use a run-time value?**
- **What's going on behind the scenes?**
- **Is the error message LTA?**

## What are the simplest compile time solutions?

You yourself provide a good compile time solution in your comment below this answer in response to my first version of it.

That said, if you wish to keep the symbol purely lexically scoped, you should start with a `my`:

```
my constant MAXVALUE = 1000_000;
```

Problem solved.

## What if you want to use a run-time value?

The variables/symbols/expressions in a `where` clause will be evaluated *at compile-time* if they're in a [`WhateverCode` expression](https://docs.raku.org/type/WhateverCode).

But that *might* not be the case if you use a lambda (with `{ ... }` syntax) instead. If the line in your code:

```
has $.c where 0 < * < MAXVALUE;
```

was changed to:

```
has $.c where { 0 < $_ < MAXVALUE }
```

then your code would work.

**BUT...**

If you add an explicit initial value to the `has` line...

```
has $.c where { 0 < $_ < MAXVALUE } = 10;
                                    ^^^^ Explicit initialization
```

...then the error would return because now the `where` clause is invoked during compile time due to a chain reaction:

- The compiler decides to check that the initialization value passes the `where` check.
- To do that the compiler evaluates the `where` clause *at compile-time*;
- That in turn causes `MAXVALUE` to be evaluated -- and it contains `Mu` at compile-time, causing the error to return.

## What's going on behind the scenes?

There are both compile-time and run-time phases in initializing `has` variables:

- During *compile-time*, when a *class* is being *composed*, the *default* value that instances will have for each `has` variable is determined. Three common scenarios are:

  | `has` statement | default value |
  | --- | --- |
  | `has $foo;` | `Any` |
  | `has $foo where some-condition;` | `<anon>` |
  | `has $foo = 42;` | `42` |
- During *run-time*, when an *instance* of a class is being *built*, the values of the `has` variables *of that particular instance* are set, possibly initializing them to values other than the class's default values.

The following code is intended to demonstrate the process:

```
BEGIN say 'code compile-time, start, outside class';
say 'code run-time, start, outside class';

sub init (*%_) { say "initializing {|%_}" }

class foo {
  has $.bar;
  has $.baz where init(baz => $_);
  has $.buz where init(buz => $_) = 42;
  say 'run-time, at end of class';
  BEGIN say 'compile-time, at end of class';
}
BEGIN say 'compile-time, outside class again';

say 'run-time, outside class again';
say foo.new(buz => 99);
```

displays:

```
code compile-time, start, outside class
compile-time, at end of class
initializing buz    42
compile-time, outside class again
code run-time, start, outside class
run-time, at end of class
run-time, outside class again
initializing buz    99
foo.new(bar => Any, baz => <anon>, buz => 99)
```

Note the completed initializations of the three `has` variables in the fully built instance:

- `bar => Any`.

  This is the usual default initialization of a variable.
- `baz => <anon>`.

  cf `say my Int $var;` which displays `(Int)`, because the default value of a variable with a type constraint but no explicit initializing value is the type object corresponding to the type constraint, and `say my $var where 1;` which displays `(<anon>)`, reflecting the anonymous nature of a `where` constraint (as contrasted with a `subset`). So `has $.baz where init(baz => $_);` results in a default value of `(<anon>)`.
- `buz => 99`.

  This is the only `has` variable for which an `initializing ...` line was displayed -- and, importantly, there are *two* lines, not one:

  1. The *first* line is displayed immediately after `compile-time, at end of class`, i.e. when the compiler reaches the closing curly of the class declaration. This is when Raku does class composition, and `buz` gets the default value `42`.
  2. Then, during evaluation of `foo.new(buz => 99);`, which builds an *instance* of the class *at run-time*, comes `initializing 99`.

## Is the error message LTA?

In my first version of this answer I wrote:

> I'm not myself able to provide a coherent explanation ... whether it's considered a bug. I do currently consider the error message LTA.

Now it's time for me to carefully discuss the error message:

```
Type check failed in binding to parameter '<anon>'; expected Any but got Mu (Mu)
  in whatevercode  at ... A\lib ... line 1
  in block <unit> at ... line 3
```

- `Type check failed ...`

  The `where` check failed. It is referred to as a "type check". Given normal Raku use of the word "type", I'm going to count this as fine.
- `... in binding to parameter '<anon>';`

  I'm not sure what "parameter" refers to, nor `'<anon>'`. Imhh (in my humble hypothesizing) "parameter" refers to a parameter of the `infix:«<»` function and `'<anon>'` to the value stored in `$.c` at compile-time before the anonymous `where` constraint is attempted at run-time.

  **LTA?** Perhaps something like `<where clause>` instead of `<anon>` would be viable and appropriate?
- `expected Any but got Mu (Mu)`

  By default, `has` variables expect `Mu`, not `Any`. So this bit of the message seems *not* to refer to the `$.c`. So, as with my hypothesis about "parameter", I think this is about a parameter of the `infix:«<»` function.

  This is really useful info. Any time you see `but got Mu (Mu)` you can be pretty sure a failure to initialize some value is part of the problem, as was indeed the case here.
- `in whatevercode`

  The blow up is happening in a `WhateverCode`, so this part is useful for someone who knows what a `WhateverCode` is.

  **LTA?** If someone does *not* know what a `WhateverCode` is, this part is cryptic. I think `in WhateverCode` instead of `in whatevercode` would be a worthwhile improvement. Perhaps `in WhateverCode (eg '* < 42')`, where the '* < 42' is fixed as literally that rather than being the actual source whatevercode, because I don't think that's doable, would be better?
- `at ... A\lib ...`

  The paths parts I've elided (`...`) are both helpful (full) and awful (long non-human friendly strings).

  **LTA?** Perhaps moving the paths to the end would help:

  ```
  Type check failed ... got Mu (Mu)
    in whatevercode at A\lib line 1

    (Full path to A\lib: D:\scripts\Raku\Raku\A\lib\.precomp\
        C6EB86CB837D3BCAAA3D85B66CE337C820700C08\
        6D\6DCD4CE23D88E2EE9568BA546C007C63D9131C1B)
  ```
- `... line 1`

  "line 1" presumably refers to either line 1 in the `whatevercode` or line 1 in the `A\lib`. Either way, it's not especially helpful.

  **LTA?** Perhaps it's viable and appropriate to make it clearer what the line 1 refers to, and, if it refers to `A\lib`, then make it accurately point to the `whatevercode`.
- `in block <unit> at line 3`

  That's useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. and use `constant MAXVALUE = 1000_000;` is ok.

Comment: I think that the problem is that, somehow, the whole `$.c ...` is turned into a whatever code by the presence of *. Which is why using an explicit lambda fixes it, because you delimit where it begin and ends...

Comment: Thanks jjmerelo, `subset C of Int where 0 < * < MAXVALUE; has C $.c;` proved too.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use a block lambda, or any lambda. `has $.c where 0 < $_ < MAXVALUE;` also works. (Note that since `where` is a smartmatch, the value that you are testing is in `$_` when the right side gets evaluated.)

Comment: @BradGilbert I agree. But that's because the variable isn't initialized in the `has` statement. I'm working on an update to my question that will explain what I see.